# select from inner join on where match against return 0 result

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, inner-join

table.a is innodb has fields `id,post_id,auther,add_date`

table.b is myisam has fields `post_id,title,content`, fulltext key(title,content)

```
select * from b 
where match (title,content) 
against ('+words' in boolean mode)
```

this could return 12 records. when run a explain, I could see the fulltext key. But

```
select * from a 
inner join b 
on a.post_id = 'b.post_id' 
where match (b.title,b.content)
against ('+words' in boolean mode)
and a.auther = 'someone'
order by a.id asc
```

this retrun 0 result. I have checked

```
select id,auther,post_id from a where auther = 'someone'
```

the return `post_id` put in mysql

```
select post_id from b where post_id = 'post_id from table a'
```

this result is exist. So where is the problem? (BTW, 2 tables post_id are all saved as varchar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you didn't intend for the join condition to be

```
on a.post_id = 'b.post_id'
```

but rather

```
on a.post_id = b.post_id
```

(The difference being that your version will join every row of `b` to any row of `a` where `a.post_id` is the string `"b.post_id"`, whereas my version will join rows of `a` to rows of `b` where their respective `post_id` columns are equal).

Comment: `on a.post_id = b.post_id` get error #1267 `Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation = `

Comment: In what character set & collation are the two `post_id` columns encoded?

Comment: thanks, fixed. one table is `utf8_unicode_ci` another is `utf8_general_ci`